# How to retrieve the temperature value (from service) to AppWidgetProvider

Tags: android, android-widget, android-service

Hi am new to to android widget, i Searched example to retrieve the temperature(its in service) to appwidget provide, but i not get clear idea on that. so for i start an service to get the temperture details.

Its my Service(here i got the temp value) Need to know how i want to pass this detials to AppWidgetProvider

```
class MainService extends Service {
    private SharedPreferences sharedPref;
    private static final String Sync_My_Settings = "SyncSettings";
    private Button tempbut;
    public static ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mDataFetchList;

    private int appWidgetId = AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        sharedPref = MainService.this.getSharedPreferences(Sync_My_Settings, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        setCurrentLocation();

        Log.e("edgar","Started Service");
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    public void setCurrentLocation() {
        String myLat= "myLat",myLong="myLong";
        loc1 = new GeoLocationUtil(this).getCurrentLocation(this);
        if (loc1 != null) {
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
            editor.putString(myLat,  String.valueOf(loc1.getLatitude()));
            editor.putString(myLong, String.valueOf(loc1.getLongitude()));
            editor.commit();
            System.out.println("PWF Latitude = " + String.valueOf(loc1.getLatitude()) + "Longitude = " + String.valueOf(loc1.getLongitude()));

            JSONWeatherTask task = new JSONWeatherTask();
            task.execute("", sharedPref.getString(myLat, "0"), sharedPref.getString(myLong, "0"));
            try {
                int myTemp = (int) task.get().temperature.getTemp();
                String City =task.get().location.getCity();

                //System.out.println("SWF HH display fd=" + result);
                mDataFetchList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                map.put("Temp", City);
                mDataFetchList.add(map);
                Intent widgetUpdateIntent = new Intent();
                widgetUpdateIntent.setAction(MyProvider.DATA_FETCHED);
                widgetUpdateIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);
                sendBroadcast(widgetUpdateIntent);
            } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    private class JSONWeatherTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Weather> {
        @Override
        protected Weather doInBackground(String... params) {
            Weather weather = new Weather();
            String data = ( (new WeatherHttpClient()).getWeatherData(params[0], params[1], params[2]));
            try {
                weather = JSONWeatherParser.getWeather(data);

                // Let's retrieve the icon
                weather.iconData = ( (new WeatherHttpClient()).getImage(weather.currentCondition.getIcon()));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return weather;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Weather weather) {         
            super.onPostExecute(weather);
            if (weather.iconData != null && weather.iconData.length > 0) {
                Bitmap img = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(weather.iconData, 0, weather.iconData.length);
                imgView.setImageBitmap(img);
            }
            String City =weather.location.getCity();
            String Cloudy =(weather.currentCondition.getCondition() + "(" + weather.currentCondition.getDescr() + ")");
            String temper ="" + weather.temperature.getTemp()  + "\u00B0C";
        }
    }
}
```

And my AppWidgetProvide

```
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    final int count = appWidgetIds.length;

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        final Intent intentt = new Intent(context, MainService.class);
        intentt.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetIds[i]);
        context.startService(intentt);
    }
    super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
}

@Override
public void onEnabled(Context context) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onEnabled(context);
}

@Override
public void onDisabled(Context context) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDisabled(context);
}

private RemoteViews updateWidgetListView(Context context, int appWidgetId) {
    // which layout to show on widget
    RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.simple_widgett);

    // RemoteViews Service needed to provide adapter for ListView
    Intent svcIntent = new Intent(context, MainService.class);

    // passing app widget id to that RemoteViews Service
    svcIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);

    // setting a unique Uri to the intent
    if (MainService.mDataFetchList != null) {
        svcIntent.putExtra("data", MainService.mDataFetchList);
        remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.btn1, "Temp");
    }
    remoteViews.setRemoteAdapter(appWidgetId, R.id.btn1, svcIntent);
    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.am, am.format(new Date()));
    Intent toastIntent = new Intent(context, MyProvider.class);
    toastIntent.setAction(MyProvider.TOAST_ACTION);
    toastIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);
    PendingIntent toastPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, toastIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    remoteViews.setPendingIntentTemplate(R.id.date, toastPendingIntent);
    return remoteViews;
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    super.onReceive(context, intent);

    if (intent.getAction().equals(DATA_FETCHED)) {
        int appWidgetId = intent.getIntExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);
        AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
        RemoteViews remoteViews = updateWidgetListView(context, appWidgetId);

        // update and notify widget when data arrives
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, remoteViews);
        appWidgetManager.notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged(appWidgetId, R.id.date);
    }
}
```

Kindly check the above code and help me to finish this task

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Service:

```
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyProvider.class);
            intent.setAction(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE);
            intent.putExtra("City", City);
            intent.putExtra("Temp", myTemp);
            sendBroadcast(intent);
```

In AppWidgetProvider Class

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    super.onReceive(context, intent);

    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

    if (bundle != null) {
         City = bundle.getString("City");
        Temperature = bundle.getInt("Temp");


        int appWidgetId = intent.getIntExtra(
                AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,
                AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);
        AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager
                .getInstance(context);
        RemoteViews remoteViews = updateWidgetListView(context, appWidgetId);

        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(currentWidgetId, remoteViews);

        appWidgetManager.notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged(appWidgetId,
                R.id.date);

    }
```